# Cannot read PHP structure array in javascript jQuery

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, html

I'm trying to read and show with jQuery a `PHP` array, explicitly, a parsed SRT subtitle file. I can see all the data together doing `console.log(data)` after `ajax` success response, but I want to manipulate the data.
My `jQuery`code:

```
var jsonURL = JSON.stringify(data);
        $.ajax({
            type: "POST",
            url: "parser_srt.php",
            data: {url: jsonURL}, 
            cache: false,

            success: function(data){
                console.log(data);
                var cont = 0;
                var data = JSON.parse(data)
                for(var i = 0; i < data.length; i++) {
                    n_ = data[i].number;
                    i_ = data[i].startTime;
                    o_ = data[i].stopTime;
                    t_ = data[i].text;

                    //is = srtToSeconds(i_);
                    //os = srtToSeconds(o_);

                    var startUp = [{ "start": i_, "end": o_, "text": t_}]; 
                    subtitles_1.push(new paragraph(i + 1, startUp[0].start, startUp[0].end, startUp[0].text));

                    if(flag == 1){
                        var startUp_trans = [{ "start": i_, "end": o_, "text": ' ' }];
                        subtitles_2.push(new paragraph(i + 1, startUp_trans[0].start, startUp_trans[0].end, startUp_trans[0].text));
                    }
                    //cont++;
                }
            }
        });
```

And the `PHP` code is this one:

```
<?php 

define('SRT_STATE_SUBNUMBER', 0);
define('SRT_STATE_TIME',      1);
define('SRT_STATE_TEXT',      2);
define('SRT_STATE_BLANK',     3);

$url = json_decode($_POST['url']);

$lines   = file($url);

$subs    = array();
$state   = SRT_STATE_SUBNUMBER;
$subNum  = 0;
$subText = '';
$subTime = '';

foreach($lines as $line) {
    switch($state) {
        case SRT_STATE_SUBNUMBER:
            $subNum = trim($line);
            $state  = SRT_STATE_TIME;
            break;

        case SRT_STATE_TIME:
            $subTime = trim($line);
            $state   = SRT_STATE_TEXT;
            break;

        case SRT_STATE_TEXT:
            if (trim($line) == '') {
                $sub = new stdClass;
                $sub->number = $subNum;
                list($sub->startTime, $sub->stopTime) = explode(' --> ', $subTime);
                $sub->text   = $subText;
                $subText     = '';
                $state       = SRT_STATE_SUBNUMBER;

                $subs[]      = $sub;
            } else {
                $subText .= $line;
            }
            break;
    }
}
echo json_encode($subs);
?>
```

Why I can't get the data inside the structure array in `jQuery`, I don't understand?

Thank you

Comment: Set the `dataType: 'JSON',` under `cache: false,` in your ajax call. And there is no need to do `JSON.parse(data)`

Comment: Can you show us what your data results look like when you receive the payload?

Comment: yes, this is the data:
[{"number":"\ufeff1","stopTime":"00:00:15,555","startTime":"00:00:14,060","text":"So this right here\n"},{"number":"2","stopTime":"00:00:19,636","startTime":"00:00:15,580","text":"is the tiny village of Elle,\nclose to Lista.\n"},{"number":"3","stopTime":"00:00:22,020","startTime":"00:00:19,660","text":"It's right at the southernmost\ntip of Norway.\n"},{"number":"4","stopTime":"00:00:25,556","startTime":"00:00:23,140","text":"And on January 2 this year,\n"},

Comment: Now, I get this, more reasonable thanks to @VIDesignz, but still can't process the data:
Array [ Object, Object, Object, Object, Object, Object, Object, Object, Object, Object, 85 more… ] 
Array [ Object, Object, Object, Object, Object, Object, Object, Object, Object, Object, 85 more… ]

Comment: Ok cool. Now you have to change `success: function(data_)` to `success: function(data)` and make sure you use that now to iterate.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I guess I'll post my comments as an answer...

First off...

Set the `dataType: 'JSON',` under `cache: false,` in your ajax call.

There is no need to do `JSON.parse(data)`

Lastly, change `success: function(data_)` to `success: function(data)` and iterate through `data` in your loop

Everything should work at this point.

Answer (score 1):

your success function defines data_ & you're console.logging data_ but you're looping through data

```
success: function(data_){
console.log(data_);
```

...

```
for(var i = 0; i < data.length; i++) {
```